# i have created stored procedure but can't able to execute same

Tags: oracle, plsql

I defined a stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure spfirst
(
  sp_loc out varchar,
  sp_sal out int
)
as
begin
  select LOCATION, MONTHLY_SALARY 
    into sp_loc, sp_sal 
    from nilesh;
end;
```

I then call the procedure and get an error

```
begin 
spfirst;
end;

ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SPNAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 4):

Your procedure takes two parameters.  You are calling it without any parameters.  Oracle thus looks for a procedure named `spfirst` that takes no parameters, finds no such procedure, and throws an error.

Something like

```
DECLARE
  l_location nilesh.location%type;
  l_salary   nilesh.monthly_salary%type;
BEGIN
  spfirst( l_location, l_salary );
END;
```

should work.  Of course, you'd generally want to do something with the variables that are returned.  If you've enabled `dbms_output`, you could print them out

```
DECLARE
  l_location nilesh.location%type;
  l_salary   nilesh.monthly_salary%type;
BEGIN
  spfirst( l_location, l_salary );
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Location = ' || l_location );
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Salary = ' || l_salary );
END;
```

Be aware that your procedure will throw an error unless the `nilesh` table has exactly one row.  It seems likely that you either want the procedure to take an additional parameter that is the key to the table so that the `select into` always returns a single row or that you want a function that returns a `sys_refcursor` rather than a procedure that has multiple `out` parameters.